# Error: "useGetRecordId could not find the current record id." when trying to test react admin component

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm trying to test the following component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Grid } from "@mui/material";
import {
  DateField,
  FunctionField,
  Labeled,
  Show,
  SimpleShowLayout,
  TextField,
  useGetRecordId,
  useNotify,
  useRecordContext,
  useRefresh,
} from "react-admin";
import cancelaLotePush from "../../api/cancelaLotePush";
import ChipStatus from "../../components/ChipStatus";

function MostraLotePush() {
  const [carregando, setCarregando] = useState(false);

  const notify = useNotify();
  const recordId = useGetRecordId();
  const refresh = useRefresh();

  const cancelarEnvio = async () => {
    setCarregando(true);
    try {
      await cancelaLotePush(recordId);
      refresh();
      notify(`Lote cancelado`, { type: "info" });
    } catch (e) {
      notify(`Erro: Não foi possível cancelar o envio do lote`, { type: "error" });
    }
    setCarregando(false);
  };

  const BotaoCancelarEnvio = () => {
    const record = useRecordContext();
    if (!record) return null;
    if (record.statusId !== 4) return null;
    return (
      <Button
        onClick={cancelarEnvio}
        sx={{ ml: 4, alignSelf: "flex-end", fontSize: 12 }}
        variant="outlined"
        color="error"
        size="small"
        disabled={carregando}
        data-testid="botao-cancelar"
      >
        Cancelar envio
      </Button>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Show title="Lote push">
      <SimpleShowLayout spacing={3}>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          <Grid item md={10} xs={12}>
            <Labeled label="Título">
              <TextField source="statusDescricao" />
            </Labeled>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item md={2} xs={12} marginTop={{ xs: 0, md: 2 }}>
            <FunctionField render={(record) => ChipStatus(record.statusDescricao, "medium")} />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Labeled label="Descrição">
              <TextField source="statusDescricao" />
            </Labeled>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item md={2} xs={12}>
            <Labeled label="Código">
              <TextField source="id" />
            </Labeled>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item md={4} xs={12}>
            <Labeled label="Data de envio">
              <DateField source="dataHoraInclusao" />
            </Labeled>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item md={6} xs={12} display="flex" alignItems="center">
            <Labeled label="Agendado para">
              <DateField source="dataHoraStatus" />
            </Labeled>
            <BotaoCancelarEnvio />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </SimpleShowLayout>
    </Show>
  );
}

export default MostraLotePush;
```

With the testing file:

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { AdminContext } from "react-admin";
import MostraLotePush from "../MostraLotePush";

describe("Monstra Lote Push", () => {
  it("Deveria renderizar corretamente", async () => {
    const { container } = render(
      <AdminContext
        dataProvider={{
          getOne: () =>
            Promise.resolve({ data: { id: 1, statusId: 4, statusDescricao: "Aguardando momento agendado" } }),
        }}
      >
        <MostraLotePush />
      </AdminContext>
    );
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

And getting the error: "useGetRecordId could not find the current record id. You need to use it inside a RecordContextProvider, or inside a supported route, or provide the record id to the hook yourself."

I have already tried to mock react-admin hooks but doesnt work, the documentation [react-admin unit tests](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/UnitTesting.html) says to wrap the test with <AdminContext> but i did and still dont work

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your component in the `<Show>` component

OR

You can wrap it in `<RecordContextProvider>` and in `value` prop provide what you have in mocked dataProvider - `{ id: 1, statusId: 4, statusDescricao: "Aguardando momento agendado" }`. In that case dataProvider on `<AdminContext>` won’t be needed.

Comment: Didnt work, when i wrap the test with <RecordContextProvider> i get this error: "No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one"